# Model validation through the combination of PCA with classifiers

Tags: python, validation, classification

I use the code below for building machine learning algorithm.
In the end, I need to validate model performance.
However, I am confused if I do it correctly or not.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import numpy as np

names = ["PCA+LDA", "PCA+SVM", "PCA+NB", "PCA+LR", "PCA+RF"]
random_state = 42  

classifiers = [
    LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(),
    SVC(kernel="linear", probability=True, random_state=random_state),
    GaussianNB(),
    LogisticRegression(max_iter=5000, random_state=random_state),
    RandomForestClassifier(random_state=random_state)
]

accuracy_progression = {name: [] for name in names}
std_dev_progression = {name: [] for name in names}

for n_components in range(1, 11):  
    final_accuracies = {name: [] for name in names}

    for iteration_model_accuracy_1 in range(20):
        X_train_val, X_test, y_train_val, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.15, random_state=iteration_model_accuracy_1)
        skf_1 = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=6, random_state=iteration_model_accuracy_1, shuffle=True)

        for train_index, val_index in skf_1.split(X_train_val, y_train_val):
            X_train, X_val = X_train_val[train_index], X_train_val[val_index]
            y_train, y_val = y_train_val[train_index], y_train_val[val_index]

            pca_1 = PCA(n_components=n_components)  
            X_train_pca = pca_1.fit_transform(X_train)
            X_val_pca = pca_1.transform(X_val)

            for name, clf in zip(names, classifiers):
                clf.fit(X_train_pca, y_train)
                y_val_pred = clf.predict(X_val_pca)
                val_accuracy = accuracy_score(y_val, y_val_pred)
                final_accuracies[name].append(val_accuracy)

        X_train_val_pca = pca_1.transform(X_train_val)
        X_test_pca = pca_1.transform(X_test)

        for name, clf in zip(names, classifiers):
            clf.fit(X_train_val_pca, y_train_val)
            y_test_pred = clf.predict(X_test_pca)
            test_accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_test_pred)
            final_accuracies[name].append(test_accuracy)

    for name in names:
        accuracy_progression[name].append(np.mean(final_accuracies[name]))
        std_dev_progression[name].append(np.std(final_accuracies[name]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine.

The code is crying out "put me in a function!" You've
[polluted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming))
the global namespace with a bunch of variables
that should be local to a function.
And you've not explained the gozinta and the gozouta.

---

## document assumptions

There's an opportunity to explain what's happening
in the module's """docstring""".

Alternatively we could wrap this code in a
function whose """docstring""" describes
the `X` and `y` it expects to receive
and the progression pair that it returns.

Or we could break out a small class that
accepts `X` and `y` and offers classifiers
based on the first `1 .. 10` principle components.
Having defined that interface, the remainder
of this code would analyze those classifiers.

On which topic, **ten** is a
[magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))
that should be named.
We could conveniently do that as a
keyword default argument in a function signature.

Similarly for the **twenty** times
we iterate through StratifiedKFold trials.

---

## use idiomatic python

```
accuracy_progression = {name: [] for name in names}
std_dev_progression = {name: [] for name in names}
```

In Fortran IV we pass around related arrays of same length,
because there isn't a better way to express Author's Intent.

But here you might find it convenient to produce 2-tuples, or even
[named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).
Then questions a caller might ask, such as
"are these two of identical length?", simply never arise.

Similarly, `classifiers` might have been defined as a bunch
of `(name, classifier)` pairs.

In any event, using a
[default dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)
here would make sense: `defaultdict(list)`

---

## extract helper

By the time you start writing the fourth nested loop

```
for n_components ...
    for iteration_model_accuracy_1 ...
        for train_index, val_index ...
            for name, clf ...
```

you really have to start asking yourself the question
"is there maybe some higher level concept lurking
within these low-level structures? Could I **name** that concept?"
The innermost loop seems especially ready for Extract Helper.

---

## unit tests

I *imagine* this code likely does what we expect it to.
But adding a small
[test suite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)
would significantly improve our understanding of what it does,
and our confidence that it is behaving correctly.

---

The pair of output progressions would benefit
from some explanatory reporting text, or Seaborn charts,
to help future collaborators evaluate whether
the results obtained are "good" or "bad".

---

This code appears to achieve its design goals.

Given the high coupling and lack of well-defined interfaces,
I would not be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks
on this codebase. It is adequate for a use-once throwaway
data assessment, but not for collaborating with a diverse
team of engineers over longer timespans.